# Mongoose saves without a required field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I am trying to test Mongoose schemas by inserting an object which is not included with some required field.

This is the case:

```
let schema = {
    _supplier: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true
    },
    permissions: {
      type: [
        {
          level: {
            type: Number,
            min: 1,
            max: 9,
            required: true
          },
          title: {
            type: String,
            minlength: 0,
            maxlength: 16
          },
          modules: [String]
        }
      ],
      validate: [permissionsLimit, '${PATH} exceeds the limit of 9'],
      required: true
    }
  };

  function permissionsLimit(v) {
    return v.length<=9;
  }

  let permissionsTestSchema = new Schema(schema);

  let PermissionsTest = mongoose.model("permissionsTestSchema", permissionsTestSchema);

  let permissionTest = new PermissionsTest({
    _supplier: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
  });

  permissionTest.save(err => {
    if (err) return cast.error(err);
    return cast.ok();
  });
```

As you can see, I make an instance which only contains the `_supplier` key - I don't add the `permissions` array - **Which is required**.

Instead of receiving an error, the Mongoose applies the action and inserts a blank array of `permissions` to the collection in MongoDB.

This is not the behaviour I need in here.
I don't wand a document in the collection which has missing details.

If user do not provide with `permissions` array to his value, I do not accept the query at all.

Why Mongoose ignores the required field in the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) in mongoose have one special feature:

> Arrays are special because they implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array).
>
> To overwrite this default, you need to set the default value to undefined

So you can change your schema to:

```
let schema = {
    _supplier: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    permissions: {
        type: [
            {
                level: {
                    type: Number,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 9,
                    required: true
                },
                title: {
                    type: String,
                    minlength: 0,
                    maxlength: 16
                },
                modules: [String]
            }   
        ],
    validate: [permissionsLimit, '${PATH} exceeds the limit of 9'],
    required: true,
    default: undefined
    }
};
```

and then your code will throw an exception with following message:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: permissionsTestSchema validation failed: permissions: Path `permissions` is required.

Comment: Great! works! Only in this case I should specify like this?

Comment: Yes, only for arrays

Comment: But I have another problem: if users sends blank array it also let it get saved - without add level, title and modules.

Comment: So maybe you can modify your `permissionsLimi` function and check if array is not empty ?

Comment: Okay I did it. But why should I do it again, if I already said that I want level, title and module which level is required?

Comment: level, title and module rules apply for nested documents inside `permissions` array, so you have to insert something into that array to trigger that validation

Comment: Okay. One more tiny question: if user updates the collection - and he passes again the `_supplier` key, but null, or with some different `ObjectId`, how to prevent this?

Comment: @Raz you can match by _supplier key when you update - if it's null or something that does not exists then no document will be updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181588/discussion-between-raz-and-mickl).